# Can I simulate named arguments or static variables?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, function

I'm making a simple asynchronous process helper - for some parsing it's better t make it slower and prevent browser from becoming unresponsive.

The "helper" class requires 2 necessary paramaters - the worker thread function that will perform the task, whatever it is and the variables, that will persist through iterations and will be eventually changed by the worker thread. Eg. *parsed text*, *progress* or whatever.

Now, the simplest way to do this would be to use object or a array:

```
ProgressManager(task, taskdata) {
   ...
   tick() {
      ...
      task(taskdata);
   }
   ...
}
var progress = new ProgressManager(function(data) {data.ticks++;}, {ticks: 0});
```

For `taskdata` is an object instance, a reference is passed to `task`. However, I'm not satisfied with that. It would be way nicer, if I could simulate the arguments like this:

```
    ProgressManager(task, taskdata) {
       var arguments = new ArgumentsObjectThatDoesNotExistAsFarAsIKnow();
       //Create some fake named arguments
       for(var i in taskdata) {
          arguments.add(i, taskdata.i);
       }
       ...
       tick() {
          ...
          task.useArguments(arguments);
       }
       ...
    }
    var progress = new ProgressManager(function(ticks) {ticks++;}, {ticks: 0});
```

I don't mind arguments being still predefined in `task` function.

Here is the whole class, it seems to work at the moment (using referecnes):

```
/**
   @arguments
     task - the function that will be performed every iteration MUST RETURN ProgressEvent instance
     taskdata - variables for the class - an object, or array so it persists and is passed as a reference
     onFinish - function that will be called when progress is over
     onProgress - this will be called every iteration
 *
 *
**/   
function ProgressManager(task, taskdata, onFinish, onProgress) {
  //Save the arguments
  this.onProgress = onProgress;
  this.onFinish = onFinish;
  this.onError = null;
  this.onPause = null;
  //Speed control variables
  this.sleep = 20;
  //Progress variables              
  var running = 0;  //0 - stoped,  1-running, 2 - paused
  this.progress = null;//Percent of progress if any - not used yet
  //Self reference for callbacks
  var _this = this;
  //Now the progress methods
  this.start = function() {
    if(running==1)
      return;
    running = 1;
    heart();
  }
  this.resume = function() {
    this.start();
  }
  this.stop = function() {
    running = 0;
    //This triggers an error too
    error({type:"Cancelled"});

  }
  //This ticks and calls task
  function heart() {
    if(running!=1)
      return;
    setTimeout(function() {tick();}, _this.sleep);
  }
  //This happens on every heartbeat
  function tick() {
    var evt = task(taskdata);
    if(typeof evt=="undefined"||evt==null||!(evt instanceof ProgressEvent)) {
      error({type:"Invalid event.", data:evt});
    }  
    if(evt.isFinished) {
      finished();
      return;
    }
    else if(evt.progress>90) {
      console.log(evt);
    }
    if(evt.isError) {
      error({type:"Progress error", data:evt.error});
    }  

    if(typeof _this.onProgress == "function") {
      _this.onProgress(evt);
    }
    heart();
  }
  //This is trigerred when job is done
  function finished(evt) {
    running = 0;
    //Trigger event
    if(typeof _this.onFinish == "function") {
      _this.onFinish(evt);
    }  
  }
  //This will handle errors
  function error(err) {
    _this.stop();
    if(typeof _this.onError == "function")
      _this.onError(err);
    if(console!=null&&console.error!=null) {
      console.error("Error happened during progress: ",err);
      throw null;
    }
    else
      throw new Error("Error happened during progress: "+ err.type);
  }
}
function ProgressEvent(finished, error, progress) {
  if(progress>=100)
    finished=true;

  this.isFinished = finished===null?false:finished;
  this.isError = error===null?false:error;
  this.progress = progress;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`func.apply(thisVal, argumentArray)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)?

Comment: Yeah func.apply calls func with each element in argumentArray as it's own argument.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, `.apply` does not pass `argumentArray` by reference. [I tested that for sure.](http://jsfiddle.net/b9fmJ/1/)